# is it possible to get the content of file1 minus file2 by using bash cmd?

Tags: bash, file

I have two files:

```
log.txt 
log.bak2022.06.20.10.00.txt
```

the `log.bak2022.06.20.10.00.txt` is the backup of `log.txt` at `2022.06.20 10:00`.

but the `log.txt` is a content-increasing file.

now I have a requirement, I want get the content of `log.txt` minus `log.bak2022.06.20.10.00.txt`, then write into a new file.
is it possible to implement it?

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own version of [logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate)?

Comment: Add content of log.txt, log.bak2022.06.20.10.00.txt and your desired output to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the small file contains N lines, and these N lines are an exact match for the 1st N lines in the big file

Sample inputs:

```
$ cat small
4
2
1
3

$ cat big
4
2
1
3
8
10
9
4
```

One `comm` idea:

```
$ comm --nocheck-order -13 small big
8
10
9
4
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '
FNR==NR { max=FNR; next }
FNR>max
' small big
8
10
9
4
```

One `wc/sed` idea:

```
$ max=$(wc -l < small)
$ ((max++))
$ sed -n "$max,$ p" big
8
10
9
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-based solution without need for unix piping `|` chains, `regex`, function calling, or `array` splitting :

```
{m,n,g}awk '(_+= NR==FNR ) < FNR' FS='^$' small.txt big.txt 

8
10
9
4
```